# Replacing href value of all <a> elemnts without link with .mp3 extention

Tags: php, preg-replace

this is my created php code for Replac a href value to new url

```
 $string = "<a href='http://example.com/test'>click here</a>
 <a href='http://example.com/test.mp3'>the site</a>";
 $newurl = "http://newurl.com";
 $pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";
 $newstring = preg_replace($pattern,$newurl,$string);
 echo $newstring;
```

now i want if links with .mp3 or .zip extentions not Replacing to new link

example : i want Replacing "http://example.com/post/1"  to `"http://myotherexample.com/test"`
     and if link url is `"http://example.com/test.mp3"`
    not Replacing and show genral url

like this output

view-source:

```
<a href='http://myotherexample.com'>click here</a>
    <a href='http://example.com/test.mp3'>the site</a>
```

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: just give the url to $newurl. No matter whether it is .mp3 or .com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(<a[^>]*?href\s*=\s*['"](?![^'"]*mp3))[^'"]*`

This will match your `<a...>` that contains an `href` where `mp3` is not found. It will capture the text up to the opening quote, and then match until the closing quote, so you can change the URL to whatever you want.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/RH6BYC/2) and you can use the [code generator](https://regex101.com/r/RH6BYC/2/codegen?language=php) on the left of the site to get the PHP version of how to match/replace this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
$string = "<p>Please <a href='http://example.com'>click here</a> to go to <a     href='http://example.com/test.mp3'>the site</a></p>";
$newurl = "http://myotherexample.com";

// Edit according to comment
$pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+\.(?!(?:mp3|zip))(?:\/?\?[^\"']*)?(?=(\"|'))/";

$newstring = preg_replace($pattern,$newurl,$string);

echo $newstring;
```

**Output:**

```
<p>Please <a href='http://myotherexample.com'>click here</a> to go to <a     href='http://example.com/test.mp3'>the site</a></p>
```

Comment: thanks but if the urls contain with utf-8 words not working Example :http://example.com?q=سلام

Comment: @hamedfarhadi:See my edit. But you should have said that in your original question.

Comment: @hamedfarhadi:What is not working? Please, edit your question and add some sample test cases and what you're expecting for each one.